# Source for plastic rack gear strips

Tags: gears

I'm trying to find a source for this type of plastic rack gear:

[image]

This image came from [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ErxoOQGvm4).

I can find short pieces of straight rack gear on ebay, but nothing like this.

It appears to be a vinyl/plastic type material, has 90-degree mounting flange, and is toothed on both sides.

Any information would be appreciated!

Comment: What forces are involved and tolerance for Stress-strain.?  Most hobbyists use 8mm toothed timing gears and belts

Comment: @sunny it's a similar application : moving a hollow core door (45lbs) on roller track. Yes i have looked at belts but was interested in this rigid type. Thx

Comment: Why plastic?  https://www.bbman.com/custom-pulleys/

Comment: @sunny cheap + quiet (mostly cheap.)